constexpr function to generate unique error codes mapped to strings
My goal is to be able to write something like this:
my_class.h
class MyClass {
    static constexpr uint32_t MYERROR = register_error("Myerror message");
    static constexpr uint32_t MYOTHERERROR = register_error("Myothererror message");
    // ...
};

somewhere_else.h
class SomewhereElse {
    static constexpr uint32_t ANOTHER_ERROR = register_error("Another_error message");
    // ...
};

I want the constexpr function register_error to assign a unique number to each call so there are no conflicts between error codes. In addition, I want a function called e.g., strerror that maps the error code back to the explanation string. Everything happening at compile-time. Does C++ offer a way of doing this?
I want the error codes so I can return them in a function upon getting an error.
int MyClass::my_func(int input) {
    if (input < 0) {
        return -MYERROR;
    }
    return 0;
}

My immediate thoughts are to use some map data structure, but it does not seem to be supported as a constexpr. I've seen some 3rd party libraries that seem to implement constexpr maps though, but I would like to see if there are any other possible solutions first.
Other suggestions on how to do per-class error handling are accepted! I'm not very familiar with C++ so there might be some obvious solutions I'm unaware of...

Presumably your idea of "unique number" is also "low and sequential" as otherwise you could just any 32-bit hashing function?

This is fundamentally impossible. You can only have 2 out of 3: constexpr-ness, ability to declare those in multiple places, and the IDs being sequental and always unique. If you abandon the latter (since you say you want the first two), you can just hash the strings.

A constexpr map in one header file is the most logical solution. You can't spread out constexpr logic over multiple files (here is my take on such a map : https://onlinegdb.com/QGUkHoJD0n) (no hashing, O(log n) lookup speed)

Making a unique number is relatively simple (just use __COUNTER__ and probably additionally hash __FILE__ if you want to). However making my_func is something that would affect compiler global state, you can exploit CWG 2118 and create such a "compile time map", but I would really advice to think twice about this.
